# Installing Wireless Printer

Tags: lexmark, password-recovery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I reset a lost Administrative(root) password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrativeroot-password)

I've been trying to install my Lexmark Platnum Pro 905 printer to my laptop with Ubuntu, and every time I try, it asks for the administrator password. What could that be, since I've tried my normal password to sign in, and that does not work?
Any idea's on what an administrator password is or where I can find it?.

Comment: Possible duplicate? - http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrativeroot-password

Answer (score 0):

You need to know your administrator password to install that driver to your computer.
Ask it for someone.

You created the password when you installed your Ubuntu.